# Select all the field names in a ROW() type column

Tags: sql, amazon-athena

I am working with a table that includes a column that is basically a payload array of data, and I am trying to get a way to pull all key names in it. I initially tried to unnest it, but got errors because the column type is a ROW().

So when I run something like:

```
SELECT DATA_TYPE 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE 
TABLE_NAME = 'tablename' AND 
COLUMN_NAME = 'column'

OUTPUT:
row(id varchar, gameid varchar, type varchar, action varchar, accountid varchar)
```

Ideally, I am looking for a way to get an output in just the form of:
| |
| -------- |
| id |
| gameid |
|type|
|action|
|accountid|

Is this something that is easily possible with ROW() type columns? Otherwise I can probably parse the original output I am getting to do what I need, but it would be nice to skip a contrived step if possible.

Answer (score 0):

If your column is in row format you can do:

```
select payload.*
from mydb
```